# Need to send disk status via OTel Collector in agent mode

Tags: open-telemetry, open-telemetry-collector, otel

We have OTel collector deployed in agent mode. This means the collector is deployed on the same machine which we are monitoring. As part of the metrics that are to be made available from this machine, we want to know the disk status something similar to:

```
drive_status{service="Disk Collector",category="Space Disk",drive="D:"} 1
```

Since drive D is connected above, this metric is shared as 1.
Is there a way to report this metric from OTel collector directly with the existing available receivers?
Or do I need to write a custom receiver for this?